# Posted multiselect box selection to database only adding the first selected item

Tags: php, mysql, insert, implode

i am using the following multiselect box to take input from users, this then gets posted to my php form which adds it to the database, the problem is, all I am getting added is the first selection, if the user selects more than one field I still only get the first field.

If the user selects lets say internet, drawing,maths I want that to be put into the database, at the moment all that is inserted is internet, or whatever is the first thing selected in the list.

My form looks like this >>

```
    <form action="../files/addtodb.php" method="post" style="width:800px;">
    <select name="whatisdeviceusedfor[]" size="1" multiple="multiple" id="whatisdeviceusedfor[]">
        <option value="games">Games</option>
        <option value="takingphotos">Taking Photos</option>
        <option value="maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="reading">Reading</option>
        <option value="drawing">Drawing</option>
        <option value="internet">Internet</option>
        <option value="other">Other (enter more info below)</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

The php side looks like this >>

```
 <?php

 // Implode what is device used for
$usedfor = $_POST['whatisdeviceusedfor'];
$arr = array($usedfor);
$whatisdeviceusedfor = implode(" ",$arr);



// Insert posted data into database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO itsnb_year5questionaire (whatisdeviceusedfor) VALUES   '$whatisdeviceusedfor'") or die(mysql_error()); 

   ?>
```

Comment: why `$whatisdeviceusedforstring = $whatisdeviceusedfor;` ???

Comment: ahh thats not supposed to be in there, I copied the section of code that applied to the problem instead of copying the whole page, I will remove it.

Comment: If the user selects lets say internet, drawing,maths I want that to be put into the database, at the moment all that is inserted is internet, or whatever is the first thing selected.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a search engine! It seems to me, that you have not even searched for that problem before posting this question.

Comment: BTW: an HTML ID musn't include most special chars like `[]` in your case. You may use them for the `name`, but not for the `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are already getting array by select so you dont need to use `$arr = array($usedfor);`this again

just try

```
$usedfor = $_POST['whatisdeviceusedfor'];

$whatisdeviceusedfor = implode(" ",$usedfor);
```

or

```
$usedfor = $_POST['whatisdeviceusedfor'];


$strings ='';
foreach ($usedfor as $item){
    $strings .=' '. $item;
}
echo $strings;
```

and

```
 <select name="whatisdeviceusedfor[]" size="5" multiple="multiple" id="whatisdeviceusedfor[]">
                                           ^^             
                                           ||change to option you want to select
```

i have changed `size="5"` so it will select now 5 at a time ...you have only 1 so it will let only 1 select at a time

result

[image]

### warning

your code is vulnerable to  **SQL injection**  also use of `mysql_*` function are deprecated use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: …which will throw an E_WARNING if the posted value is not an array. (`Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`) You should at least cast it to an array: `implode( ' ', (array) $_POST['whatisdeviceusedfor'] );`

Comment: Enable your error reporting and execute `implode` with a string as second parameter – then you'll see the error. (Yes it could be a string if the client sends one – it's a user input don't trust it and always set the data type you're awaiting. Just because sometimes an array was sent, that doesn't mean at all that an array will always be send.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, that works like it was wanting now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have selected mutliple items via a `SELECT` or via `CHECKBOXES`, the form will return an array-like data structure. You will always need to loop over that data and store each item individually into the database or concatenate the values to a string before inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$usedfor` is contain the array you can directly use it in `foreach` to save the each value in the value.Try this it may help you:

```
<?php   
$usedfor = $_POST['whatisdeviceusedfor'];

foreach($usedfor as $arr){
mysql_query('INSERT INTO itsnb_year5questionaire(whatisdeviceusedfor) VALUES("'.$arr.'"') or die(mysql_error()); 

}
```

Comment: will this put all the values together into a string ?

Comment: @Iain Simpson No. Was that a requirement? Than you should ask for it.

Comment: what you want to add each value as an individual records or in a single record

Comment: This gives me >> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''games'' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

first change `size = "5"` to see good the list

then try to make like that (its second option if you like it)

```
if ($_POST) {

  // post data

 $games = $_POST["games"];
 $takingphotos = $_POST["takingphotos"];
 .
  ...


  // secure data

  $games = uc($games);
  $boats = uc($takingphotos);
  .
  ...
 }   


  // insert data into database

  $query = "INSERT INTO itsnb_year5questionaire (games, takingphotos,....)   
             VALUES('$games','$takingphotos',......)";
     mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo 'Thanks for your select!';
```